# How can I write this VBA code more efficient?

Tags: vba, excel

is there a possible way to write this piece of VBA code more efficient?

With the use of for loops or so?

And make it more general, not with the fixed cells?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Range("A31").Formula = "=index(Optional_Processes,1)"
Range("A32").Formula = "=index(Optional_Processes,2)"
Range("A33").Formula = "=index(Optional_Processes,3)"
Range("A34").Formula = "=index(Optional_Processes,4)"
Range("A35").Formula = "=index(Optional_Processes,5)"
Range("A36").Formula = "=index(Optional_Processes,6)"
Range("A37").Formula = "=index(Optional_Processes,7)"
Range("A38").Formula = "=index(Optional_Processes,8)"
Range("A39").Formula = "=index(Optional_Processes,9)"
Range("A40").Formula = "=index(Optional_Processes,10)"
Range("A41").Formula = "=index(Optional_Processes,11)"
Range("A42").Formula = "=index(Optional_Processes,12)"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to do it in one hit would be:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Range("A31:A42").Formula = "=index(optional_processes,row()-30)"
End Sub
```

This wouldn't put 1,2,3 etc as the last argument but when placed on row 31 it will return 1 (`row()-30`) and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `For` loop, like this:

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To 12
    Range("A" & 30 + i).Formula = "=index(Optional_Processes," & i & ")"
Next i
```

---

**2nd Option**:

```
Dim CellStart As Range

Set CellStart = Range("A30") ' set the Start Cell anchor

For i = 2 To 12
    CellStart.Offset(i).Formula = "=index(Optional_Processes," & i & ")"
Next i
```

Comment: @NickKuipers your'e welcome, now comes your part where you mark as "ANSWER", by clicking the gray check-mark on the left side of my answer (it will turn green)